# Problem connecting MySQL DB in Visual Studio using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework, mysql-workbench

I'd like to use Entity Framework in Visual Studio.

I select "Add new" -> "Devart LinqConnect Model" -> Database First and then select 127.0.0.1, port number 3306, my user without password and the name of my DB (hr here). And I got the next error :

> Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061): Authentication failed.

When I'm using MySQL Workbench I can use my DB connect to it and execute query.

Answer (score 0):

According to the devart linq connect the host can be left empty if it is localhost, try leaving it blank and see if it works, sometimes using the loopback direction doesn't work (I don't have the knowledge in this particular case though).

If you want you can check the docs here https://www.devart.com/linqconnect/docs/

Comment: Hi, I just tried that but I doesn't solve the problem.. :/

Comment: I would try adding a password then. if it isnt that then im out of ideas

Comment: I already tried using a password but it doesn't change anything